# Can I use forward auth only for some domains with traefik?

Tags: oauth, traefik

I would like to use traefik with forward auth using an oauth provider. In traefik, forward auth config is tied to an entry point.

However, I only want to apply foward auth to some of the configured domains. Domain configuration is not part of the entrypoint config.

Is this possible without deploying a "child traefik" behind the initial one?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fixing this on the traefik side it might be done on side of the forward auth provider, e.g. doing something like https://github.com/thomseddon/traefik-forward-auth/issues/36. Downside is that every request will take an additional round-trip to the auth provider.

It might also be possible- I have not tested this- to use a traefik frontend to redirect to an *additional* entry point where only that entry point will have forward auth configured.